# Using destroy in tkinter the root disappear but the script keeps running

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tkinter, destroy

I have done a script that process some images and at the end, it asks you where do you want to save the file. I made it using tkinter (code below). It works fine, the only problem that I have is:

I have an exit button linked with the function `destroy` and when I click it, the root is closed, but the script is still running, no error appear and I have to stop it manually. If I use `quit` the script is stopping but the root window freezes and kernel error appear restarting python. I tried to use `sys.exit()` after the `root.mainloop` but the script is not going out of the loop. Hope you can help, thank you.

I am using Spider, python 3.7.6, Ipython 7.19.0

```
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x150') 


  
# function to call when user press 
# the save button, a filedialog will 
# open and ask to save file 
def save(): 
    filename2 = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='wb+',defaultextension=".tif", title="Choose filename")
    if not filename2:
        return
    
    imwrite(filename2, stack, imagej=True)# 
    # root.destroy()

    
button_save = Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save()) 
button_save.grid(row=1,column=2) 
button_exit=Button(root,text='Exit program', command=root.destroy)
button_exit.grid(row=5,column=2) 


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No issues here, running from CLI/IntelliJ. Any chance the issue could come from the rest of your code? And what's ```stack```, in the ```imwrite``` call?

Comment: Thanks for answer. stack is an array representing a 4D image (x,y,z, and wavelength). The code in principle works fine, it process the images and they are saved in a good way. What I do in the code is a bucle where I separate the different dimensions of the array, I generate masks and I take out their background, then I put them together again. Do not know what can be the problem, since no error appear :S. Maybe some package strange interaction thing in my computer?

Comment: @OctaveL is solved, I answered below. Do not know exactly why. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, perhaps it helps someone in the future.

I defined a new function to quit as follows:

```
def _quit():
    root.quit()     
    root.destroy()
    
button_exit=Button(root,text='Exit program', command=_quit)
```

Comment: root.quit() is the magic line.